# TypeError: ObjectId is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I m trying to add CRUD operation in my code.but when I am trying to load data and post data this error is showing.Although I have imported const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
but don't know why error is occuring..

```
 app.get('/product/:id', async (req, res) => {
            console.log(req.params.id);
            const id = req.params.id;
            const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
            const result = await productCollection.findOne(query);
            res.send(result)
        })
```

error:

```
:id
D:\Node\warehouse-management-server-side-Yasmin-Akhter\index.js:42
            const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
                                 ^

TypeError: ObjectId is not a function
```

Comment: Try:
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');

Insted of:
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

Answer (score 0):

import ObjectId from mongodb as

```
const {ObjectId} = require('mongodb')
```

and add 'new' before using ObjectId in query as

```
const query = { _id: new ObjectId(id) };
```